# Sync Tomboy through Ubuntu One and local folders

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, dropbox, tomboy

Is there a way to synchronize Tomboy Notes through Ubuntu One and also to a local folder? I'd like to have it sync online with Ubuntu One but also create back ups in a Dropbox folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [inoticoming](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/inoticoming.1.html) in the repositories. With this, you should be able to sync to a local directory, and have inoticoming initiate a copy of the files to somewhere else (DropBox, Ubuntu One) as the changes come in. This will also allow you to keep a copy of the previous version somewhere else as well, as I think it lets you perform an operation on the existing files using one of its options.

Answer (score 0):

I admire this goal, but I don't believe it's possible; as far as I can tell, you can only choose one synchronisation method (such as Tomboy Web, to sync online with Ubuntu One), not two.

Answer (score -1):

Set up the TomBoy sync to point to your Ubuntu one or DropBox folder and everything should work as you wish. Go Edit/Preferences in Tomboy, and make sure that Local Directory Sync Service add-in is enabled. Then, under the Synchronization tab, specify the directory (DropBox or Ubuntu One) to sync to.

I'm making the assumption here that you are alright with the single target, as DropBox and Ubuntu One are local folders in addition to being 'cloud' synced folders.

To have it go to multiple places, you should be able to create a new directory that is the target of the 'sync', and `ln -s` it to both DropBox and Ubuntu One. I think this will have it local, and also synced with both services.

Comment: To add a folder to Ubuntu One, you should actually add it (right-click, Ubuntu One, Synchronise this folder), not symlink to it from the Ubuntu One folder.

Comment: Thanks, hadn't actually done it before. It looks like symlinking into a DropBox directory will work but I don't think that will help him here.