# Access Tomboy Notes from Windows

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, tomboy

I have a dual boot system with Windows 7/Ubuntu 11.04. Is there any way I can access my notes from Windows, even though they were created in Ubuntu?

I sync my notes against Ubuntu One, so the notes are accessible in the cloud as well as on my computer. Read access is priority one, but if there is a possibility to add/edit notes from Windows as well, that'd be great.

Comment: Take a look into [this](http://osmanov-dev-notes.blogspot.com/2011/02/export-all-tomboy-notes-into-htmlxhtml.html)

Comment: @nitstorm: Thanks, but I'd like to find a solution where I can access my Tomboy notes without having to do anything in Ubuntu first. If I'm in Windows and realize I need something from a note, I don't want to have restart the computer, export the note(s), restart again and import them - they should just be readily available.

Comment: You can make it run the script as a cron job so that it runs at a particular time everyday or every few hours. So that it stays updated regularly.

Comment: @nitstorm: Doesn't that still require Ubuntu to be running?

Comment: Yeah, but atleast you get to read your tomboy notes on Windows.

Comment: Do you use Ubuntu One? You can easily view and edit your notes on the web using Ubuntu One dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, install Tomboy notes in Windows ( http://projects.gnome.org/tomboy/download.html ).

Then use your U1 to sync the contents of .local/share/tomboy with the equivalent folder created by the Tomboy app under Windows.

For more information, you can check this similar question [Sync Tomboy through Ubuntu One and local folders](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28115/sync-tomboy-through-ubuntu-one-and-local-folders)